# Laravel 5.2 - Unexisting route doesn't lead to 404 page

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm testing my web app, now I just tried to type an unexisting URL to see how the app manages it. I did expect to see the 404 page (I also have a custom one into view\errors\404.blade.php), but Laravel shows the message `Session store not set on request...`.

I've read that this message is shown when a route is not registered into the web middleware, but an unexisting URL of course is not registered.

I thought to catch the `NotFoundHttpException` into the `app\Exceptions\Handlrer.php`, but that doesn't work, because that's not the exception thrown.

How do I have to do to be redirected to the 404 page when an unexisting URL is requested?

EDIT: I've just understood that the error is due to a partials which I import into the view. That's the header which contains the form to login, so the problem is the call to the CSRF token, but why does that works if I call `App::abort(404)` and not if the exception is thrown? What do I have to do to manage this case correctly?

Comment: I may be wrong, but while you are in development mode, you will always see details like that when an errors occurs, but not in production mode.

Comment: I've tried to switch to production environment, now it only shows the `Whoops, looks like something went wrong` message and not the detailed error, but the 404 page is not shown.